# Custom scoring in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

How do i use the following function? (For elastica in PHP with respect to Function Score query)

addScriptScoreFunction($script, $filter)

Does the filter filter out results or only score based on the script for those that pass the filter? How efficient is the scoring?

Also can i add more than one script score function to function score query?

Answer (score 1):

```
$keyword = 'foo';
$fiels = 'name';

$inner_query = new Elastica\Query\Match();
$inner_query->setFieldQuery($field, $keyword);

// Wrap the function_score around the initial query

$scorefunction = new Elastica\Query\FunctionScore();
$scorefunction->setQuery($inner_query);
$scorefunction->setBoostMode('replace'); // Otherwise it will be multiplied with _score

// Make the custom score function: boost max 20% of initial _score, depending on popularity

$script = new Elastica\Script("_score + (doc['popularity'].value * 0.2 * _score)/100");
$scorefunction->addScriptScoreFunction($script);

// Last step: put that all in Elastica\Query and execute with Elastica\Search
```

There are some possible pitfalls:

- without `->setBoostMode('replace');` the original _score will be multiplied with the result of the script. As in my case the addition was desired, therefore 'replace'.
- It seems that divisions are rounded down. As the popularity that I used in my formula is allways between 1 and 100, thus popularity/100 alone was allways rounded down to 0 and the formula seemed to have no effect.